# Is there any way to redirect/auto-scroll to the next section of my html doc and not allowing manual default scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am currently making a website, where the user shouldn't be able to scroll, and when he does try to, it takes him to the next section, something like this:

```js
console.log('scroll to the next div');
/*Not sure if I can make the run snippet appear without js*/
```

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

   body {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
   }

  .sec1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .sec2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .sec3 {
    background: steelblue;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title> section scroll auto </title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="sec1">
    ...
</section> <!--on scroll, go to next div/section-->
<br>
<section class="sec2">
    ...
</section>

<section class="sec3">
    ...
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to achieve this without the use of jQuery? I've tried using anchor tags with href as the id of the next section, but it's not that efficient: it doesn't give me much control over the scrolling. I have a vague idea of what I can do, but I want a clear explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I'm a stack overflow newbie. I don't understand why the run code snippet option didn't appear. I believe I put all css, js and html?

Comment: To use the snippet, you can either type in Ctrl+M to open the snippet tool, or you can click on the 'Snippet' button, to the right of the 'Image' button in the top-menu

Comment: Well it's not supported on phones and tablets

Comment: I've submitted an edit for you. If it's approved, your code will appear as a snippet

Comment: Aw thanks for doing it yourself

Comment: There's an error, if I edit it on my tab, then will the snippet reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any JS for this. You can accomplish it with pure CSS using `scroll-snap`. You can read the official docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) and look at a tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

  .sec1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .sec2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .sec3 {
    background: steelblue;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  .sec1, .sec2, .sec3 {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title> section scroll auto </title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="sec1">
    ...
</section> <!--on scroll, go to next div/section-->
<section class="sec2">
    ...
</section>

<section class="sec3">
    ...
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh thanks a ton, and is there any way to reduce the sensitivity of the scroll?